# Cómo migrar una página web a una app Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Antes que nada, soy nuevo en Android, y quiero aclarar que ya he investigado y he buscado tutoriales, lo que pretendo hacer es, única y exclusivamente, que en una aplicación Android se pueda guardar información mediante un formulario el cual contiene: `EditText` y `Spinners`. Cabe aclarar, que esto ya lo tengo hecho en una página web, pero ahora quiero crear la aplicación que realice la misma función, o sea, guardar.

También quiero aclarar, que esto ya lo he hecho antes en java, pero llevo días y días buscando en Internet y no encuentro ningún ejemplo similar. También, de lo poco que he encontrado, he intentado adaptarlo a lo que necesito y nada. ¿Acaso es muy complicado lo que quiero hacer o acaso es más difícil realizar este tipo de cosas en Android?

Bueno, no pretendo que me hagan el proyecto, pero ¿alguien podría orientarme de qué es lo que necesito hacer?

Después de investigar sus consejos decidí intentar hacerlo de forma nativa y hasta el momento llevo lo siguiente, pero tengo problemas al guardar los formatos de fecha y no tengo idea de como guardar los `spinners`

Anexo la imagen de mi formulario(el botón que guarda dice siguiente porque pretendo hacerle algunos cambios aún)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el **xml** de la imagen de arriba es el siguiente:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.server.guardar_a.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_tiempodeuso"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtv_tiempouso"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Tiempo de uso:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtv_tiempouso"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtv_docente" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="time"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Hora de Inicio"
                android:textColorHint="#424242"
                android:id="@+id/txt_horainicio"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_fechadeuso"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Fecha de uso"
                android:textColorHint="#424242"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_horainicio"
                android:id="@+id/txt_fechadeuso"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_practica"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:onClick="mostrarCalendario" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sp_docente"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sp_tiempodeuso"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sp_tiempodeuso"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Docente:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/txtv_docente"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_horainicio"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/txt_practica"
                android:hint="Practica"
                android:textColorHint="#424242"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Siguiente"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_form1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sp_tiempodeuso"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="41dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Mi clase **JSONParser**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser(){
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url){

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();

            json = sb.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }


    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params){

        try{
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else if(method == "GET"){

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Buffer Error","Error converting result"+e.toString());
        }

        try{
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Y mi **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText practica, fechauso, horainicio;
    private Button botonform1;
    Spinner n_docentes, t_uso;
    private int anio, dia, mes, hora, minuto;
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO=0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener oyenteSelectorFecha;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://wservervv.esy.es/laboratorio/guardar_solicitud.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            practica = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_practica);
            fechauso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_fechadeuso);
            horainicio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_horainicio);
    //        t_uso = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_tiempodeuso);
    //        n_docentes = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_docente);
            botonform1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_form1);
            botonform1.setOnClickListener(this);

        fechauso.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        ArrayAdapter adapter_d = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Nombres_Docentes, R.layout.spiner_item_lab);
        n_docentes.setAdapter(adapter_d);
        ArrayAdapter adapter_t = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Tiempo_Uso, R.layout.spiner_item_lab);
        t_uso.setAdapter(adapter_t);

        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        anio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        oyenteSelectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                anio = year;mes = monthOfYear;dia = dayOfMonth;mostrarFecha();
           /*     try {
                    Thread.sleep (5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // Mensaje en caso de que falle
                }   */
                horainicio.requestFocus();
            }
        };

        fechauso.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                //Si tiene el Foco esconde el teclado y muestra el datePicker
                if(hasFocus){
                    closeSoftKeyBoard();mostrarCalendario(fechauso);
                }
            }
        });

        horainicio.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                //Si tiene el Foco Esconde el teclado y muestra el timePicker
                if(hasFocus){
                    closeSoftKeyBoard();
                    mostrarTime();
                }
            }
        });
            }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View args0) {
        if(args0 == horainicio){
            closeSoftKeyBoard();
            mostrarTime();
        }
        if(args0 == botonform1) {
            String practicaa = practica.getText().toString();
            String fechausoo = fechauso.getText().toString();
            String horainicioo = horainicio.getText().toString();
            //        String t_usoo = t_uso.getText().toString();
            //        String n_docentess = n_docentes.getText().toString();
            new CreateUser().execute(practicaa, fechausoo, horainicioo);
         }
        }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Guardando.....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Todo Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String practicaa = args[0];
            String fechausoo = args[1];
            String horainicioo = args[2];
//            String t_usoo = args[3];
//            String n_docentess = args[4];

            try{
                List params = new ArrayList();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("practica", practicaa));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fecha_prestamo", fechausoo));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hora_prestamo", horainicioo));
//                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("horas_uso", t_usoo));
//                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idusuario", n_docentess));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

                Log.d("Registering attempt", json.toString());

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(success == 1){
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Registering Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usuario guardado con exito... ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){

            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public void mostrarTime(){
        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minuto = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        horainicio.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute+":00");
                     //   t_uso.requestFocus();
                    }
                }, hora, minuto, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    public void closeSoftKeyBoard() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id){
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, oyenteSelectorFecha, anio, mes, dia);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mostrarCalendario(View control){
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }

    public void mostrarFecha(){
        fechauso.setText(anio+"-"+(mes+1)+"-"+dia);
    }
}
```

El **strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Guardar_A</string>

    <!-- Spinner docentes  -->
    <string-array name="Nombres_Docentes">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item>Juan</item>
        <item>Pedro</item>
        <item>Jose</item>
    </string-array>

    <!-- Spinner tiempo de uso  -->
    <string-array name="Tiempo_Uso">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item>1 Hora</item>
        <item>2 Horas</item>
        <item>3 Horas</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Mi tabla **préstamos**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mis archivos php:

**db_config.php**

```
<?php
define('DB_USER',"u557976579_swgvv");
define('DB_PASSWORD',"guardar_a");
define('DB_DATABASE',"u557976579_bdser");
define('DB_SERVER',"mysql.hostinger.mx");
?>
```

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {

    function __construct(){
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->close();
    }


    function connect(){

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    $con = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

    $db = @mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    return $con;
    }

    function close(){

        mysql_close();
    }

  }
?>
```

**guardar_solicitud.php**

```
guardar_solicitud.php
<?php

$response = array();

//if (isset($_POST['idusario']) && isset($_POST['fecha_prestamo']) && isset($_POST['hora_prestamo']) && isset($_POST['horas_uso']) && isset($_POST['practica']) && isset($_POST['idusuariosolicitud'])){
if (isset($_POST['fecha_prestamo']) && isset($_POST['hora_prestamo']) && isset($_POST['practica'])){
    $nombredocente = 4;
    $fechauso = $_POST['fechauso'];
    $horainicio = $_POST['horainicio'];
    $timeuso = 1;
    $practica = $_POST['practica'];
    $usuariosolicitud=1;

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO prestamo(idusuario,fecha_prestamo,hora_prestamo,horas_uso,practica,idusuariosolicitud) VALUES('$nombredocente', '$fechauso', '$horainicio', '$timeuso','$practica', '$usuarioquesolicita')");

    if ($result){

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error ocurred.";       

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}else{

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";      

        echo json_encode($response);

}

?>
```

Eso es lo que tengo hasta el momomento

Comment: ¿Quieres migrar de forma nativa a Android o simplemente hacer que el formulario se vea en una app Android? ¿En que formato es el formulario (json, php...)?

Comment: Si lo que deseas es guardar datos de la misma manera y en la misma bd de tu sitio, entonces debes de darle un vistazo a webservices, hay infinidad de tutoriales, uno de ellos es  [este](http://picarcodigo.blogspot.mx/2014/05/webservice-conexiones-base-de-datos.html ) o que es lo que quieres, no muy le entendí.

Comment: Vicky Vicent me gustaria ambas o la mas sencilla, el formulario que tengo en la pagina web es php y html5

Comment: @x4mp73r si eso es lo que quiero, ya vi muchos tutoriales pero no se si por el tiempo en que fueron creados cuando intento implementar me marcan errores, ademas muchos vienen con otros modulos como actualizar, eliminar, mostrar y si elimino esos modulos me generan mas y mas errores, si puedes mira [este](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/crear-un-webservice-para-android-con-mysql-php-y-json/) he intentado unicamente implementar la parte de insertar pero al tener muchos modulos y utilizar fragments marca muchos errores por eso preguntaba si es mas complejo hacerlo en android que en web

Comment: Mirate Phonegap es un framework hibirdo Android/Html5

Comment: Puedes usar cordova, https://cordova.apache.org/
O phonegap http://phonegap.com/
Además, el código javacript que generes, se podrá usar para multiples plataformas, como Android o Iphone.

Comment: Para pasar una Web a Android, te aconsejaría que miraras lo que los compañeros dicen. Phonegrap tiene buena reputación. Si no, la forma mas sencilla es utilizar una app con un simple WebView, pero seria un poco... "cutre". Si quisieras pasarlo a Android nativo seria un poco mas costoso según tu nivel. Para mi no, pero a lo mejor para ti si.

Comment: ¿Sabes? He estado pensado sobre tu pregunta y realmente no es tan difícil de hacer. Si puedes poner un ejemplo de tu formulario web (una imagen) y decir que utiliza para eniar los datos, es decir, si envías los datos en formato JSON desde un archivo PHP, te pongo un ejemplo encantada. :)

Comment: Ok @Vicky Vicent si me permites en un momento subire lo que tengo ya que ya consegui guardar los datos de Edit Text de tipo number y parson name pero algo no cuadra con el tipo date y time, ademas de que me cierra la aplicacion despues de guardar los datos, por cierto ya vi phonegrap y tuve problemas porque lo que quiero migrar a android solo es un modulo de todo lo que tengo en la pagina web y sobre WebView por lo mismo que mencionas ya no lo utilize

Comment: Perfecto, entonces estaré al tanto de las modificaciones. :)

Comment: @Vicky Vicent ya realize las modificaciones, en la fila 8 de la tabla prestamos guardo perfectamente el EditText de tipo parson name pero los de tipo Date y Time los deja en ceros, alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Te llega a salir en los `EditText` las fechas? Por cierto, te recomiendo el uso de `HttpUrlConection` en vez de `DefaultHttpClient`. [Aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13197/4684) tienes un ejemplo de una respuesta que dí, solo tendrías que añadir tus métodos `POST` y `GET`.

Comment: gracias por la recomendacion y si me sale la fecha por ejemplo me sale: 2016-6-8 y en la hora: 12:51:00 pero lo guarda 0000-00-00 y 00:00:00, segun creo que debo convertir el string a date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si tienes ya tu codigo en HTML que realiza esa acción simplemente puedes cargar tu página en un `WebView` dentro de tu app, dejando el HTML en un archivo local de la aplicación, ahora si lo que quieres es pasarlo a un formulario nativo de Android como mencionas con EditText y Spinners necesitaras primero realizar un webservice para la comunicación de la app con tu base de datos (crear registros, extraer catalogos de información para los spinners, etc...).

Comment: Tienes razon es una posible solucion, sin embargo siento que mejor debo implementarlo de forma nativa, estoy intentandolo como lo sugeriste con webservice

Answer (score 7):

Buenas, en realidad si ya tienes la página funcionando en el navegador es en realidad muy fácil ya que con **apache cordova** puedes pasar tu código a un proyecto con este framework, el cual sirve para crear aplicaciones híbridas para los diferentes sistemas operativos ios,android etc, hay herramientas que nos ayudan a realizarlo mas rápido como **ionic, jquery mobile ,onsen UI** etc.

apache cordova: [dar click para ir a la página!](https://cordova.apache.org/)

ionic framework: [dar click para ir a la página!](http://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: Bueno creo que no especifique, me disculpo mi pagina la tengo de manera local, e intente usar el framework  phonegap pero digamos el resultado que obtuve no era el esperado, quizas hay errores en la forma que hice mi pagina web, voy a ver como me va con el que me sugeriste, gracias por responder

Comment: asi es, el apache cordova es una buena opción