# Error "NullPointerException" al ejecutar un AsyncTask en Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estoy trabajando en una actividad de Android que consulta a una base de datos para rellenar un ListView, os dejo el código:

```
    private class EjecutoConsulta extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<Comunicado>>{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Comunicado> datos) {
       if (datos!=null){
           rellenaDatos(datos);
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Comunicado> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url="http://192.168.0.193/estructuraNueva/scripts/leerComunicados.php";


        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(url);

        String respuesta;


        JSONObject json=null;
        JSONArray jArray=null;

        try {


            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();

            respuesta=httpclient.execute(httpGet,responseHandler);
            json=new JSONObject(respuesta);

            jArray=json.getJSONArray("datos");

        }catch (Exception e){


            System.out.println("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");


        }

        ArrayList<Comunicado> datos=new ArrayList();


        for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject object=null;

            try {

                object=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Comunicado comunicado=new Comunicado(object.getString("id"),object.getString("titulo"),object.getString("texto")
                ,object.getString("imagen"),object.getString("link"));


                datos.add(comunicado);


            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV");

            }

        }

        return datos;
    }
}
```

Cuando desconecto el servidor, me salta este error:

```
06-08 09:05:02.413 24754-29704/com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa, PID: 24754
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
at com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.ComunicadosListado$EjecutoConsulta.doInBackground(ComunicadosListado.java:149)
at com.example.oftecnica2.appcorporativa.ComunicadosListado$EjecutoConsulta.doInBackground(ComunicadosListado.java:100)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Entiendo que salta al no poder consultar, pero si tengo todo entre `try{}catch(){}`, no entiendo por que detiene la app. ¿Alguna manera de que aunque no pudiera consultar, siga corriendo como si nada? (Lógicamente con el listado vacío).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede determinar el problema si revisas el mensaje:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

El problema se provoca cuando intentas acceder al método `length()` de la instancia `jArray` que es nula.

```
 for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
...
```

Regularmente se valida con un manejo de excepciones.

```
...
...

ArrayList<Comunicado> datos=new ArrayList();
   try {
        for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject object=null;

                object=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Comunicado comunicado=new Comunicado(object.getString("id"),object.getString("titulo"),object.getString("texto")
                ,object.getString("imagen"),object.getString("link"));


                datos.add(comunicado);

              }
     }catch (Exception e){
              System.out.println("Ocurrion un problema: " + e.getMessage());    
     }              

        return datos;
...
...
```

Con esto se "soluciona", pero lo mejor es evitar que ese valor sea nulo para no provocar problemas más adelante en el flujo de tu aplicación.

> ¿Alguna manera de que aunque no pudiera consultar, siga corriendo como
>   si nada?

Te sugiero dos opciones, la primera: puedes realizar una validación mediante un operador terciario, si no encuentra el array "datos", crea un array vacío y con eso evitas manipular valores nulos:

```
//jArray=json.getJSONArray("datos");
   JSONArray  jArray = jObject.has("datos") ? jObject.getJSONArray("datos") : new JSONArray();
 for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
 ...
 ...
```

La segunda: que considero la más importante, es revisar porque tu petición no obtiene datos o si contiene datos, porque no contiene el array json "datos".

```
respuesta=httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
json=new JSONObject(respuesta);         
jArray=json.getJSONArray("datos");
```

**La solución correcta sería que si no se encuentran datos, tu petición regrese el array "datos" vacio.**

Otro punto que no tiene que ver con la pregunta, es que se recomienda dejar de usar la clase [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) para conexión, ya que es una clase marcada como obsoleta:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url="http://192.168.0.193/estructuraNueva/scripts/leerComunicados.php";
HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(url);
```

en su lugar usa [**HttpUrlConection**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) , te recomiendo ver la implementación de esta clase en el `Asynctask` de la respuesta de @VickyVicent .

Comment: Muchas gracias Elena, solucionado asi, gracias a todos por vuestra participacion :)

Answer (score 2):

La excepción te esta dando por que cuando haces el for abajo del todo el jArray es nulo y no puede sacar la propiedad length (como esta el try catch esta dentro del bucle no tiene en cuenta esa excepcion), para que te funcionara deberis sacar el try catch fuera del bucle for asi:

```
try {
for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

        JSONObject object=null;



            object=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Comunicado comunicado=new Comunicado(object.getString("id"),object.getString("titulo"),object.getString("texto")
            ,object.getString("imagen"),object.getString("link"));


            datos.add(comunicado);




}
}catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV");

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si te sirve de algo, yo para coger datos de un archivo JSON que me manda un servidor, utilizo el siguiente `AsyncTask`. Lo he modificado con tus datos para que puedas utilizarlo directamente, aunque yo paso parámetros desde el método `onCreate()` al `AsyncTask`, tu puedes codificarlo.

Llamada desde el `onCreate()`;

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Iniciamos constantes
        // Nombre el array del JSON. EN tu caso será "datos"
        ARRAY_JSON_ROOT = "datos";
        // URL del archivo PHP que manda los datos en JSON
        URL_PHP = "http://192.168.0.193/estructuraNueva/scripts/leerComunicados.php";
        // Ejecución del AsyncTask
        new getData().execute(URL_PHP);

    }
```

Clase `AsyncTask`:

```
public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Comunicado>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                // Se declara un ArrayList para guardar los datos que necesitamos
                 ArrayList<Comunicado> datos = new ArrayList();

                // Se establece una conexión a través de la URL_PHP pasada en la llamada al AsycnTask
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // Si esta conexión se establece correctamente, continuará con el proceso. Si no
                // retornara null
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                    // Se almacena los datos recibidos de la petición en un buffer (espacio de
                    // memoria reservado del sistema) y lo convierte en una cadena de String con
                    // StringBuilder.
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }

                    // Como el resultado será una cadena de String con formato JSON, debemos
                    // convertir esta esta cadena en un objeto JSON para poder manipularlo. En este
                    // caso lo convertimos finalmente en un JSON Array para poder seleccionar solo
                    // los campos de datos que necesitamos.
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                    JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray(ARRAY_JSON_ROOT);

                    // Añadimos tantos add como datos queramos coger del JSON y con el tipo de 
                    // valor, ya sea "getString()", "getInt()", "getBoolean"...
                    for (int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

                        Comunicado comunicado = new Comunicado(item.getString("id"), item.getString("titulo"), item.getString("texto"), item.getString("imagen"), item.getString("link"));

                        datos.add(comunicado);

                    }
                    // Devuelve al método "onPostExecute" el ArrayList con los datos
                    return datos; 
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("IOException", e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i("JSONException", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) connection.disconnect();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Comunicado> datos) {
           if (datos!=null){
               rellenaDatos(datos);
           }
        }
}
```

No te he respondido a tu pregunta, pero te de dado un `AsyncTask` más completo y con el que no he tenido nunca ningún problema. Espero que a ti tampoco te los de.

De todas formas revisa el código por si me he dejado algo de tu código que no sepa.

Si sigue estando nulo una vez hayas implementado el código que te dejo, revisa el archivo `PHP`, puede que el fallo este ahí.

Y para terminar solo decirte que el fallo que te esta dando es porque tu jArray es nulo y puede ser por dos cosas:

- Porque no este recibiendo nada del archivo `PHP`.
- Porque los `try{}catch(){}` estan afectado y en todo caso tendría que englobar todo el código en uno solo.

Mucha suerte y si tienes alguna duda, pregunta sin miedo.

¡¡Suerte con tu app!!

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando acceder a `jArray.length()` cuando `jArray` es nulo.
Una manera de solucionarlo podría ser modificando la condición del bucle:

`for (int i=0;jArray != null && i<jArray.length();i++){`

También podrías incluir todo el código dentro del mismo `try{}catch{}`.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí dejo otra manera que yo suelo usar mucho de comprobar si un valor que contiene un JSON existe:

```
   jArray = json.has("datos") ? json.getJSONArray("datos") : null;

   if(jArray!=null){
   // do something
   }
```

Saludos